# Submit an array to a function as a list of arguments

Tags: javascript

Must be processed array prior to transmission in a function such that each element of the array has been selected that argument. Method .join fails, as it makes object that [object Object]. How is it best to do, given that the size of the array is not fixed and can be changed?

Example:

```
function test(a, b, c) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3];

//array processing

test(arr);
```

And console return

`1`
`2`
`3`

The function can not make changes. Number of elements in the array can be different.

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)....e.g.:`test.apply(window,arr);`

Comment: Thank! Thank you! It works! I could not run an hour!

Answer (score 3):

It is not entirely clear where you are stuck.  You can just pass the array to the function and check the `.length` of the array inside the function like this:

```js
function test(items) {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        document.write(items[i] + "<br>");
    }
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
test(arr);
```

---

If you wanted to pass a variable number of arguments to the function and see how many arguments are passed, you can use the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) that is present in every function:

```js
function test() {
    // arguments.length is the number of arguments passed
    // arguments[i] is each argument
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        document.write(arguments[i] + "<br>");
    }
}

test(1,2,3,4,5);
```

---

If you're trying to figure out how to take an array of elements and pass them as the arguments for a function, then you can use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```js
function test(a, b, c, d) {
    document.write(a + "<br>");
    document.write(b + "<br>");
    document.write(c + "<br>");
    document.write(d + "<br>");
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
test.apply(null, arr);
```